# Button created inside ajax call behaves differently than in standard html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to create a table, populated by an ajax query where each row has a delete button next to it, so it can be easily removed.

However if I try to build the button inside an ajax query it doesn't seem to post correctly.
To ensure it wasn't the code inside the jquery click I created this simple function

```
$('.delbutt').on("click", function(event) {
    var confirm = window.alert("good button pressing skills!");
    return false;
});
```

The ajax query and div table filling is handled by this:

```
(function ajaxMapCalls() {
    $.ajax({
        url: mapgrabber,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
            $("#vcmaps").empty();
            var output1 = "<table><tr><th>Customer</th><th>vCenter</th><th>Cluster</th><th>vSwitch</th><th></th></tr>"

            $(data).each(function(i, el) {

                var output2 = "<tr><td>" + el.customer + "</td><td>" + el.vcenter + "</td><td>" + el.cluster + "</td><td>" + el.vswitch + "</td><td><button class='delbutt'>delete</button></td></tr>";

                output1 += output2;
            });
            $("#vcmaps").append(output1 + "</table>");
        }
    });
    setTimeout(ajaxMapCalls, 2000)
})();
```

The table buttons are there it all builds fine but the button doesn't behave as expected, there's not a simple jquery popup and it seems to attempt to post server-side which it shouldn't be doing at this point.

So I tried putting a copy of the buttin inside the html.

Html of the relevant section below

```
<form action="#" method="POST" id="custVCassign"><div id="vcMenu" 
class="flip"><h3>Assignment</h3></div>
<div class="panel">
Customer: <select class="select" id="custbag"></select><br>
vCenter: <select class="select" id="vCenter"></select><br>
Cluster: <select class="select" id="vCluster"></select><br>
Distributed switch: <select class="select" id="vSwitch"></select><br>
<button id="custvcdel" class="button2">Delete Cluster and Switch</button>
<button id="custvc" class="button">Add Cluster and Switch</button><br>
<button class='delbutt'>delete</button></form>
<div id="vcmaps"></div>
</div></form>
```

The button INSIDE the html works absolutely fine, it does the alert, but any buttons generated by the ajax into the div "vcmaps" don't behave correctly.

I wondered if it was because it was a div futher down and it was changing to a traditional post action so I wrapped the div in another form..

```
<form action="#" method="POST" id="custVCen"><div id="vcmaps"></div></form>
```

Still the same.

Any ideas what's going on here?

Comment: A 500 error means something has gone wrong on the server, not your JS code.

Comment: It shouldn't even be attempting to touch the server at this point. This is why I think it's switching post modes, which WOULD cause the 500. I'm asking how to stop it switching to a full post, or if even that's what it is.

Comment: More usefully what difference would putting the button inside the query rather than outside cause it to attempt to talk to the server rather than just do the alert?

Comment: You could try using web browser dev tools, go to the network tab and check what HTTP requests are fired when pressing the button. Might help narrow down the problem. You can see exactly what type of request is hitting the server and responding with the 500 error.

Comment: Thanks, I can look at that. Any idea why it's even attempting to go to the server when all it should do is pop up a window.alert?

Comment: Might want to try adding type='button' for your button. It could be defaulting to a submit button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "click" event handler won't catch buttons that are created dynamically by the ajax call. They don't exist yet when the event handler is called, so it ignores them. And since you didn't specify a `type="button"` attribute for your dynamic buttons, they default to `type="submit"`, which, if the button is inside a form, will cause your form to be submitted using a full postback when they're clicked (and there's no click handler to override this).

Use *delegated event handling* to get round this. You set the event on an element which will definitely exist when the event handler is called, and then tell it to delegate the events down to any elements which match the secondary selector at the time when the event fires. I don't know what element would be the lowest common ancestor of your buttons, so I've just used `document` as an example:

```
$(document).on("click", '.delbutt', function(event) {
```

See the "Direct and Delegated events" section here: http://api.jquery.com/on/ for more details.

Secondly, use `preventDefault()` to ensure there's no secondary postback triggered by the button. Put:

```
event.preventDefault();
```

as the first line of your "click" handler. See https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/ for more info. This is more reliable than putting `return false;` at the end of your function, because it means there's no potential time gap between the event firing and the prevention of the default.

Comment: Thankyou, I've got it working. That makes complete sense now. Of course it doesn't exist on startup.